# Artifact in bones pile?

Tags: nethack

I died.  A lot.  As a lawful valkyrie.

So, I've been trying to #dip for Excalibur, and haven't had any success yet. One of the Gnomish Mines levels was a bones level for me, and I found a cursed sword named Excalibur.

Is this the artifact, or am I still able to #dip for the real Excalibur?  I don't want to waste a holy water on a boring old sword if it isn't an artifact...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is. Nethack uses the name of artifacts on certain base item type (such as long sword for the Excalibur) as a way to identify the actual artifact. ([This can be abused to rename ID some artefacts](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Artifact_naming_trick), note that some online servers fix this).

Comment: Sadly I tried taking on a swarm of fire ants instead of scaring them off, so I never got a chance to try and uncurse it.  Good info to know though...thanks.

Answer (score -1):

If you try to name any potential artifact, it will resist naming thus establishing its authenticity.